# What is the difference between "%" and "$" in linux command prompt?Which is more favored and when?

Tags: linux, command-prompt

It is specified that % has to be used with commands like grep,ls etc however it works with a $ in ubuntu.

Comment: please give examples of the commands you are using...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it a programming question ? Or a linux using question ?

Comment: `$` is `sh` or `bash` default command prompt. `csh` and `tcsh` uses `%`. `#` is usually root shell. Don't know if it *is* what was asked. What and where is 'specified'?

Comment: its a linux using question....i am beginner...and was facing this issue

Comment: It's not an issue, you can set any command prompt you want. "It is specified that % has to be used with commands like grep,ls etc" - this doesn't make much sense to me, at least not out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I got your question right, but the '$' sign refers in Linux as an indicator for a variable. 
For instance, you can create your own variable and print them with the echo command in the terminal.

But I think you want know, that the dollar symbol is used as the prompt in Linux (if you open a new terminal)!?